# INSERT another field using number from the same id when insert new value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'am using sql server 2012
my table like

table : Order

```
|idOrder| idCustomer | dateTransaction| invoice |
| 1001  | 104        | 2014-06-09     |         |
```

idOrder using autoincrement, I want to ask how get id order that just inserted and combine with date transaction, 
my SP for insertOrder :

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Order
(
 idCustomer,
 transactionDate,
 invoice
)
VALUES
(
 @idCustomer,
 GETDATE(),
 CAST(datepart(year, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(datepart(month, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(@idCustomer AS VARCHAR(10))
)
END
```

so far I get

```
|idOrder| idCustomer | dateTransaction| invoice     |
| 1001  | 104        | 2014-06-09     |  201406104  |
```

what I want is

```
|idOrder| idCustomer | dateTransaction| invoice     |
| 1001  | 104        | 2014-06-09     |  2014061001 | --> 1001 is idOrder
```

how to get idOrder (auto increment) into invoice field at the same time when insert new data / or

how exec SP update after exec SP insert to get the idOrder, because IdOrder is autoincrement so it's no a parameter

thanks

the complete code that works !

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Order
(
 idCustomer,
 transactionDate,
 invoice
)
VALUES
(
 @idCustomer,
 GETDATE(),
 CAST(datepart(year, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(datepart(month, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(@idCustomer AS VARCHAR(10))
)
END
```

DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
UPDATE TR_Order
SET Invoice = CAST(Invoice AS VARCHAR) +  CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR)
WHERE IdOrder = @ID

Comment: MySQL / SQL Server. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

First Insert the record and get the inserted ID by using

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY()
OR
@@IDENTITY

DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
UPDATE TABLE_Name
SET Invoice = CAST(Invoice AS VARCHAR) +  CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR)
WHERE IdOrder = @ID
```

Then update the table again, because you cannot get the ID until you insert the record.

Comment: so I can't get the ID when exec SP insert? and must process SP insert and SP update after ID inserted? can we exec SP update after SP insert in SP insert code? can you give me sample, thank you

Comment: In the same procedure you can add above lines after your current code, so after insert it will get the ID and then update the record as you want.

Comment: so it's like 
DECLARE @ ID INT
SELECT @ ID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Order
(
 idCustomer,
 transactionDate,
 invoice
)
VALUES
(
 @idCustomer,
 GETDATE(),
 CAST(datepart(year, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(datepart(month, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(@idCustomer AS VARCHAR(10))
)
END
BEGIN UPDATE Order
SET Invoice = CAST(Invoice AS VARCHAR) +  CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR)
WHERE IdOrder = @ ID

like that? -- sorry for the space after @

Comment: Insert Into order (....) values (....)  select @id = scope_identity() update ....

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your record
2. Get the id
3. Perform Update to that record

Let's say we have this table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), col1 VARCHAR(32));
```

Now here's your code

```
DECLARE @id INT;

 -- here is your insert statement (1)
INSERT INTO my_table (col1) VALUES('000');

-- get the id (2)
SET @id = scope_identity(); 

-- perform update to that record
UPDATE my_table     
SET col1=col1 + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR)
WHERE id=@id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed94973fdfe451caddd4ca8d902ef207)